Can we add a button inside Textfield in Storyboard based UIKit application?
I created a textfield and  button in storyboard inside a stack view.I want my button to be inside textfield. For this inside code I have written :
    textField.rightView = button
    textField.rightViewMode = .always

In story board I have  set height and width constraints for both of them, My button has width 30 and height 30.

I have an error

What constraints should I give to place my button inside Textview.

Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate more how can I remove it from superview as I never used storyboards before and always used programatically


AFAIK, dragging a view into UITextField as a left/right view is not permitted on Interface Builder (Storyboard/Xib). Therefore, it must be added programmatically.

You cannot edit the textField rightView frame/constraint directly. To make it work, you need to sub-class UITextField and override the rightViewRect function. Basically, you don't need to provide any constraints for the button. However, the tappable area is only inside the parent view (UITextField).


class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        .init(x: self.frame.width - 60, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
    }
}

